# Получение токена VK

Tags: java, вконтакте

Привет.
Взял отсюда код по получению токена VK: http://habrahabr.ru/post/144813/. Но он нерабочий.
Приведу код ниже.

```
public class Token {

public static void main(String[] args) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, URISyntaxException, ParseException {
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=APP_ID&scope=audio&redirect_uri=http://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&display=page&response_type=token");
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);

    System.out.println(response);
    post.abort();

    String HeaderLocation = response.getFirstHeader("location").getValue();

}

}
```

`String HeaderLocation = response.getFirstHeader("location").getValue();` - эта строчка ищет заголовок "location". Но такого заголовка нет! Все, что есть, это:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK [Server: nginx, Date: Sat, 11 Oct 2014 20:08:25 GMT, Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8, Content-Length: 7019, Connection: keep-alive, X-Powered-By: PHP/3.8422, Set-Cookie: remixlang=0; expires=Sun, 04 Oct 2015 03:18:29 GMT; path=/; domain=.vk.com, Pragma: no-cache, Cache-control: no-store, X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN]
```

Не могу понять, в чем дело.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решения я вам не подскажу, надо изучать api вконтакте более детально.

Но почему ваш код не работает, могу сказать, для начала внимательно прочитайте [Авторизация клиентских приложений](https://vk.com/dev/auth_mobile).

Там в принципе все расписано, но я объясню, в ответ на ваш запрос возвращается не редирект (и соответственно заголовка "Location" нам нет), а страница, которая предлагает ввести логин и пароль для авторизации пользователя, редирект будет только при условии, что пользователь уже авторизирован.

Статью на хабре не могу прочитать, так как хабр не доступен. Но боюсь, что эта статья устарела.

Варианты:

1. Использовать браузер для авторизации, в десктопных и мобильных приложения, есть всякие вебвью и прочее.
2. Возможно, есть метод в вк апи, с помощью которого можно напрямую передать логин и пароль, но могу предположить, что он не рекомендован к использованию.